# In an "If" statement, is it better to use a return statement to end the code, or use "else" instead?

Tags: javascript, optimization, return, fetch-api

Just curious as I believe both of these functions do the same thing... I just am curious which is better/ more optimized.

```
fetch("AN API").then((response) => {
  response.json().then(({ error, data }) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

or

```
fetch("AN API").then((response) => {
  response.json().then(({ error, data }) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's likely that they're compiled identically or the difference is negligible.

Comment: I prefer the former, reducing the nesting, but it's up to you how to handle these situations.

Comment: BTW, I don't like `return console.log(error);`. You should only give a parameter to `return` if you specifically want to return that value. Since `console.log()` doesn't return anything useful, it makes no sense to return its value. It should be `console.log(error); return;`

Comment: Though, I've heard of doing `return void console.log()` to explicitly state that you don't want to return anything. It's not a common practice though.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is a clear cut right answer. It’s based often on personal preference and team convention. Personally, I like the return statement. It reduces further nesting and thus, in my opinion, is easier to read. This becomes more pronounced the more code you add into the if statement. The end result, however, is that the code remains the same.

Comment: Agreed. With smaller cases like this, either way works. But when there's a lot inside the if, definitely prefer an early return to avoid nesting - otherwise the code can become really hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the compiler and the language. Sometimes, an error will occur in the function that says "the function has reached an end without having a return statement". However, it is easier to understand in the long run if you use the else statement.

I would say you should leave the else statement out. Using an else statement takes up some compiler space.

Comment: The question is specifically about JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The first paragraph suggests that you should use the else statement, but the second paragraph recommends not using it.

Comment: Sorry about how unclear my answer. Due to JavaScript, you will be ok with leaving out the else statement, just leave a comment to make sure people know what is happening in your code.

The purpose of the first paragraph is to tell you that using an else statement can cause errors in the compilation in other languages, such as C/C++, and so you wouldn't use an else statement, while in other languages not having the else might have cause errors. 

Sorry for the confusion, I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these functions do the same thing, but in a complex code 1st one will take less resources, as it might skip a few conditions to check(depending on your code).

Just make sure to **follow same practice throughout your project**, that way its easy to maintain in long run.

And as mentioned by [COleson,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8915530/coleson) It's a personal preference and team convention.

Comment: I doubt either one would be faster. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if both code snippets turned into the same machine code/byte code/whatever the particular js engine uses.